# how to count NAs in mean calculation

Tags: r, mean, na

Very simple question, I'm sure it's been answered and I'm just phrasing it incorrectly but I want to calculate the mean of a vector of numbers including NA values, here's an example:

`dummy<-c(1,2,NA, 3)`

with this I can use mean with na.rm=T and receive the mean of 2, but what I want to receive is the mean of 6/4, including the NA value as a place holder which would return 1.5.

Comment: `sum(dummy, na.rm=TRUE)/length(dummy)`??

Comment: Could also work to just make all the `NA`s 0

Comment: @BenBolker When would it give a different answer?

Comment: I found a way to do this inside the mean function a while back I have just forgotten what it was... I know it's possible without summing and dividing over length....

Answer (score 3):

How about just swapping NA values with 0 temporarily.

```
mean(ifelse(is.na(dummy),0,dummy))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sum` and `length`

```
> sum(dummy, na.rm=TRUE)/length(dummy)
[1] 1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are a lot of ways to do this, here goes another solution:

```
mean(replace(dummy, is.na(dummy), 0)) ## 1.5
[1] 1.5
```

Just out of curiosity, the most efficient solution seems to be the sum/length by Jilber:

```
bigdummy <- rnorm(1000)
bigdummy[sample(1:length(bigdummy), 100)] <- NA

library(microbenchmark)
mean_length <- function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/length(x)
mean_replace <- function(x) mean(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)) 
mean_ifelse <- function(x) mean(ifelse(is.na(x),0,x))


microbenchmark(mean_length(bigdummy), 
               mean_replace(bigdummy), 
               mean_ifelse(bigdummy), 
               times=1000L)


  Unit: microseconds
                   expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
  mean_length(bigdummy)   4.033   4.400   5.499   5.866  109.976  1000
 mean_replace(bigdummy)  25.661  27.128  28.594  29.327  198.690  1000
  mean_ifelse(bigdummy) 142.602 144.802 145.902 152.500 3405.209  1000
```